# Stricter Reporting of Python Code Coverage

Tags: python, unit-testing, report, code-coverage

Suppose I have two Python modules in my project:

```
/project
  /module1
    __init__.py [Empty]
    class1.py
  /module2
    __init__.py [Empty]
    class2.py
```

`Class1` has some functions, but the important one is `doEverythingAndGetData()`. Let's pretend it gives a number back while executing several internal functions.

Now suppose that `Class2` uses `Class1`, and then has further functionality implemented. `Class2` only has two functions - `__init__` and `foo()`.

```
def foo(self):
    #Create an instance of Class1
    class1 = Class1()

    #Get some information using class1
    data = class1.doEverythingAndGetData()

    #Do some logic on the data, it doesn't matter
    result = (data + 10) * 2

    #Return the result
    return result
```

Now I want to write a unit test for Class2 that covers `foo()`.

```
def test_Class2_foo():
    #Create the Class2 object
    class2 = Class2()

    #Get the result
    bar = class2.foo()

    #Compare the value
    expectedBar = 1337
    assert expectedBar == bar, "Mismatch! {} != {}".format(expectedBar, bar)
```

This unit test is the only one written for the project. We run the unit test and generate a Code Coverage report.

After examining the Code Coverage report, we will see that `Class2` is well covered, as we have have our unit test and it is doing what it is supposed to. Fantastic!

However, we also note that `Class1` is also well covered, as the unit test *also* covered `class1.doEverythingAndGetData()` and any of it's underlying functions. Our report is showing fantastic coverage for the entire project! Send it to the PO and let's take an early weekend!

This is misleading though. What I really want the report to show is `Class2` being covered, as we have written a unit test that covers the module reliably. I **don't** want it to show `Class1` as being covered, as we don't have any unit tests that check it's internal functionality. It simply *assumes* that `Class1` works correctly, and if the unit test fails, it's description will not be very helpful nor transparent if `Class1` is at fault.

So, to simplify:

- `Class2` is covered appropriately via Unit Testing
- `Class1` has **no** direct coverage and puts the project at risk
- When Unit Tests are ran and the Code Coverage report is generated, it incorrectly shows *both* modules as well tested
- Instead, I'd like the report to show that `Class2` is covered, as `foo()` is explicitly called by the test, and `Class1` is not covered, as it's functions are called within `Class2.foo()`

This leads me to the following questions:

1. Is there a way to prevent this from happening in the coverage report?
2. What, if any, is the term to use to refer to this type of coverage?
3. Is there a particular coding pattern that helps prevent this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to provide a fake number to `class1.doEverythingAndGetData()`. As a result, the `doEverythingAndGetData()` function is never called, it just returns a value. This is called `unittest.mock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) the data coming from `class1.doEverythingAndGetData()`. In your current implementation, the *actual* code inside that function is being run whenever you call the unittest for `class2`. Something like this will help you,

```
from mock import patch
import class1

@patch('class1.doEverythingAndGetData')
def test_Class2_foo(self, doEverythingAndGetData):
    # Let's assume we are mocking 10 as the return value
    doEverythingAndGetData.return_value = 10

    class2 = Class2()

    # This will take mocked value in its implementation
    bar = class2.foo()

    #Compare the value
    expectedBar = 1337
    assert expectedBar == bar, "Mismatch! {} != {}".format(expectedBar, bar)
```

Now you can write a separate `unittest` for `class1.doEverythingAndGetData()` and get the correct coverage report!

So answering your 3 questions,

> Is there a way to prevent this from happening in the coverage report?
>
> Is there a particular coding pattern that helps prevent this issue?

Yes! Use [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

> What, if any, is the term to use to refer to this type of coverage?

In some sense, what you've done could refer to [integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) tests, where you test a number of functions together against a series of input combinations. In [unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) tests on the other hand, you test *every* function and try to see its working without caring about whether dependent functions work or not.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your detailed response. I'll try out this solution and see if it fits what I need, but it looks like it should! However, suppose that `class1.doEverythingAndGetData()` returns a much more complicated object than simply `10`. Will this work similarly for that case?

Comment: Yes, you will need to mock data accordingly. Try to have multiple unit tests where you mock different representative data